# Remove App Catalog from site collection on premises

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, app-catalog

I have a problem with App Catalog in an on-premises farm, somebody created it previously and it's not working correctly (I am a farm admin, and I'm unable to access it). I want to remove it, and create it again, but there's no option in Central Administration to do that. Nor there is a powershell command, the only one Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog is for SP Online. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried making yourself a Site Collection Administrator of the App Catalog via central admin? Being farm admin doesn't mean you have access to the sites, you have to give yourself access.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete sites, including the App Catalog, from Central Admin -> Application Management -> Delete Site Collection or use [Remove-SPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/remove-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps).

As a farm admin, I would make sure you set the User Policy on your Web Application to provide yourself with Full Control which will allow you full control on all sites in that Web Application without having to promote yourself to SCA on a per-site basis.